# NiFi: Add dropdown menu for user input

Tags: apache-nifi

Trying to work something out in NiFi with user input.

This is my requirement:
I need take user input in an attribute and based on the input values I'll do a RouteOnAttribute. The user input contains multiple options (6 altogether). Is there a way I could input the user options in one single attribute as a drop down selection mechanism?

I don't want to user separate attributes for separate input options. And other than that, I can't think of anything in UpdateAttribute processor.

Is there any other such processor available for this requirement? I couldn't find any so far(quite new to NiFi).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a custom processor that has a PropertyDescriptor that uses AllowableValues which will produce a drop-down menu of choices.

In the onTrigger method you would obtain the allowable value that was selected and add an attribute to the flow file using that value.

Comment: Can you please provide an example for an XMl file? would love to see the structure. Thank you @Bryan!